# SwiftUI Issue - Extraneous argument label 'perform:' in call (Xcode 11 Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5, xcode11

I am learning Swift and trying to implement the "Room" app demonstrated in the [WWDC 2019 Session 204](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/204/) . In my code below, which is exactly typed same as Jacob in the video but I run into the following error:

Line:

```
.onDelete(perform: deleteRoom)
```

Error:

> "Extraneous argument label 'perform:' in call"

Can't figure out on my own...

Thanks in advance!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    //var rooms: [Room] = []
    //    @ObservedObject var store = RoomStore()
    var store = RoomStore()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section {
                    Button(action: addRoom) {
                        Text("Add")
                    }
                }

                Section {
                    ForEach(store.rooms) { room in
                        RoomCell(room: room)
                    }
                    /* HERE is the error */
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteRoom)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Rooms"))
            .listStyle(.grouped)
        }
    }

    func addRoom() {
        store.rooms.append(Room(name: "New Room", capacity: 20, hasVideo: true))
    }

    func deleteRoom(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        store.rooms.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[image: Meme]

## Don't Trust Xcode:

Xcode is not very intelligent to tell you what is the real issue in SwiftUI enough (yet). So believing or not, the issue is with the `listStyle`.

You should change it to:

```
.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
```

<sub>Don't forget to remove the `.` from `.Text("Add")` you accidentally typed in first section.</sub>

---

#### Some other useful notes (NOT related to the issue):

SwiftUI API is now more compatible with `String`s, So you can set the `Text` value directly in some **initializers** for `View`s like `Button` and **modifiers** like `navigationBarTitle`:

```
Button("Add", action: addRoom) /* Instead of Button(action: addRoom) { Text("Add") } */
```

```
.navigationBarTitle("Rooms") /* Instead of .navigationBarTitle(Text("Rooms")) */
```

Comment: Thanks Mojtaba! Your suggestion does fix this error. Now I need to figure out why the "Add Room" feature not working. Seems the "BindableObject" protocol used in the video is now deprecated...

Comment: Thats another question with another topic. Please feel free to ask a new question with more details about the issue. You can then post the link of the new question here. I’m sure I can help you with that. ;)